# Changing ruby generated select to checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im very much new to ruby, but working on a new clients project and im wanting to change the current dropdown they have into multiple checkboxes but not sure how or if possible.

Current code is:

```
<%= f.label :section,t(:pick_admin_options)%><br/>
<% options =  (@admin_permission.action == :edit) ? section_options('edit') : section_options %>
<%= f.select :section, options_for_select(options,:selected => @admin_permission.section) %>
```

Anyone have any ideas? much appreciated in advance!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, This should do the trick:

```
<%= f.input :sections, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => 
((@admin_permission.action == :edit) ? section_options('edit') : section_options) %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, i gave that a go and get undefined method `input' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x000000076853d8> ?

Comment: Are you using formtastic?

Comment: i think so yes, do |f| is on the form and i see f.select etc.. being used... sorry im not a ruby guy.